# Download file in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, download, windows-phone, resume

I need to download file from website to iso storage.

I found 3 ways, `BackgroundTransfer`, `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest`, but none of these 3 ways can pause and resume downloading.
On the other hand, the 3 ways all write stream downloaded after download is complete.

How to achieve breakpoint to resume download?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know on which platform you are working, i mean you are working on windows phone 8/7 or desktop applications. In my senario if you are working on windows phone 8 than you can use the TransferControl on UI and BackgroundTransferRequst in xaml.cs. BackgroundTransferRequest has the capability to resume or pause the download. Read following link.

[Click here for TransferControl in windows phone 8 and BackgroundTransferRequest.](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/08/15/creating-a-ui-for-background-transfer-requests.aspx)

Use HttpClient inplace of webClient, with HttpClient you can do pause and resume during download file.